# How to add property to existing object on JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm fetching data from API and i would like to add property to my object.
I'm currently adding image property but i need to add this one layer deeper inside object.

Could you give me a hint how to achieve that?

I have stuck on this moment:
[image]

My code:

```
const Review = () => {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  const [people, setPeople] = useState(null);

  const fetchPeople = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      let test = Object.entries(data).map((people) => ({
        ...people,
        image: "image url goes here",
      }));
      setPeople(test);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPeople();
    console.log(people);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using object.entries was bad idea :D
Solution for my question is:

```
  const fetchPeople = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      const peopleWithImages = data.map((person, index) => {
        return {
          ...person,
          image: `https://robohash.org/?set=set${index + 1}`,
        };
      });

      setPeople(peopleWithImages);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPeople();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.entries returns an array [index, value] . You just need to add image property to value which is an object.

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
  const newData = Object.entries(data).map(people => {
    people[1].image = "some image here"
    return people;
  });
  console.log(newData);
});
```

Comment: @adiga Using map here because forEach doesn't return an array. It really depends on the use case. Here, the OP wanted to use that array (array of arrays) in setState, that's why used map.